# Where to specify window component's position?

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, module, platform

I created module in netBean platform, then I created window component there, and I want to specify default position in main window. For exapmle position "editor". Where I can do it?

Comment: I know that I can do it when I am creating the window component, but what if the component is yet created?

Comment: You may want to include more details about what is not working for you...  This will help keep folks from giving you answers that you know are going to be wrong.

Comment: @vkraemer: There is no problem about something not works for me. The problem is, that I cannot find where I can specify position of yet created window component.
Detailed description::
I created new module. I clicked on the package in it by right mousebtn, select New>>Window Component. Wizzard appears. In this wizzard I can specify "Window position" in step 2. I finish the wizzard. Now, when the Window component is created, where I can change "Window position"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like the NB WindowManager has a way to specify a position for a window in a manner similar to what you are asking.  The screen is broken up into areas (known as modes) and there are methods that let you position a window/TopComponent into a mode.

There is [a document that provides a good overview of the NB windowing system](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-windows/org/openide/windows/doc-files/api.html#create). It has links to more detailed info that will help you.

Edit:

Another strategy to use to reposition a window is to edit the layer file associated with your module. This file is usually called 'layer.xml'.

Look for an entry like the following

```
<folder name="Windows2">
    <folder name="Components">
        <file name="MyEditorWindowTopComponent.settings" url="MyEditorWindowTopComponentSettings.xml"/>
    </folder>
    <folder name="Modes">
        <folder name="editor">
            <file name="MyEditorWindowTopComponent.wstcref" url="MyEditorWindowTopComponentWstcref.xml"/>
        </folder>
    </folder>
</folder>
```

Change the name of the subfolder under "Modes" to match the value that you want as the new position/mode...

Answer (score 4):

Under NetBeans 7, to change from 'output' position to 'editor' position:

In your Window class, change the annotation

```
@TopComponent.Registration(mode="output", openAtStartup = true)
```

to

```
@TopComponent.Registration(mode="editor", openAtStartup = true)
```

Then you need to clean and rebuild.  If you don't clean it, it won't pick up the changes for some reason - probably caching.

Comment: I don't have this annotation on my class. I tried adding it manually but, the `@TopComponent` annotation isn't even available for import. I'm using NetBeans 7.4

Comment: @Zoltán According to [the documentation](http://bits.netbeans.org/7.4/javadoc/org-openide-windows/org/openide/windows/TopComponent.html) it should be available. If `import org.openide.windows.TopComponent` doesn't work for you, you may have a problem with your classpath.